# 301 Redirects Work, Rewrite Rules Used for Redirects Not Working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Below is our .htaccess file. All the 301 redirects work fine. After that in the file none of the middle ReWriteRule that we're using for redirects work. The first rewrite rule for store/locations.php is a very simply one and should work fine.

I do recognize that after that simple rewriterule, all the other rewriterules contains a "?" and that may require we do some other things (ie. escape out the "?" ). But I can't even get the rewrite rule to work on the simply url so want to know what we might be doing wrong.

What's interesting is that the Rewrite Condition & Rewrite Rule at the bottom of the .htaccess file does actually work fine (converts any non www url to a www url).

```
Redirect 301 /store/index.php http://www.pelleline.com
Redirect 301 /store/contact-us.php http://www.pelleline.com/contact-us.php
Redirect 301 /index.html http://www.pelleline.com
Redirect 301 /index.htm http://www.pelleline.com
Redirect 301 /store/index.html http://www.pelleline.com
Redirect 301 /store/index.htm http://www.pelleline.com

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^store/locations.php?/?$ http://www.pelleline.com/locations.php [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^store/product-list.php?a_testoni_shoes-pg1-cid46.html?/?$        
http://www.pelleline.com/a-testoni-shoes/cid-46-1.html [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^store/product-list.php?alden_shoes-pg1-cid47.html?/?$     
http://www.pelleline.com/alden-shoes/cid-47-1.html [L,R=301]



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't match against the query string in a rewrite rule, you need to use the `%{QUERY_STRING}` var in a condition:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/?$
RewriteRule ^store/locations.php$ http://www.pelleline.com/locations.php [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^a_testoni_shoes-pg1-cid46.html?/?$
RewriteRule ^store/product-list.php$ http://www.pelleline.com/a-testoni-shoes/cid-46-1.html [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^alden_shoes-pg1-cid47.html?/?$
RewriteRule ^store/product-list.php$ http://www.pelleline.com/alden-shoes/cid-47-1.html [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for input. That doesn't seem to work. It does look close to some other things I've tried but it's not working.

Comment: it's so strange, other parts of the .htaccess file, including the last rewrite condition (non www to www) work fine, but no matter what method I use, including the above, to redirect/rewrite specific those urls of the site, they get ignored

Comment: this worked perfectly actually, thank you! My issue was that there was a second .htaccess file in a subfolder that was keeping this great code from working. Thanks again